# GIMP: how to print on larger paper than A3?

Tags: printing, gimp

I used to be able to print on "A3+" sheets via GIMP, but after upgrading to GIMP 2.10 I lost that possibility. And downgrading to 2.8.22 didn't fix it.

The dialog to choose paper size is limited to A3:

[image: paper size dialog]

Then in the print settings, I'm not able to increase the print size or lower the resolution (trying to go for 1440 dpi here):

[image: image settings print dialog]

Is there a way to make GIMP accept to print on larger paper?

I'm on Windows 10

Comment: Paper size for printing is often depends on printer too. Have you tried changing to another printer? (e.g. Adobe PDF or Microsoft XPS document writer)

Comment: I had tried that, but that page setup dialog appears before I can choose the printer so it didn't change anything. However, now I just tried changing the default printer (and then restarting GIMP) and then it allowed me to choose more sizes :) So problem solved, I think

Comment: Actually, not fully solved: now when I change the paper size and orientation in the Page Setup dialog, it's not saved :(